# How to delete the row from table using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to delete the row from table using angularjs. But it is not working properly, It delete the previous row. Not the correct row. How to rectify this.
Please see the working [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/fjkBP6PLqoiTBmxd8RDK?p=preview)

Code snipped

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="tasksCtrl">
    <div>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="task in tasks">
                    <td>
                        <a class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-ng-click="removeRow(task)">Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

        app.controller('tasksCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
            $http.get("data.json")
                //$http.get("/todo/api/v1.0/tasks")
                .success(function(response) {
                    console.log(response.tasks)
                    $scope.tasks = response.tasks;
                });

            $scope.removeRow = function(task) {
                $scope.tasks.splice(task, 1);
            };
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the index of trying to delete

to do that,

```
 $scope.removeRow = function(task) {
     // get the index
     var index = $scope.tasks.indexOf(task);

     //delete the element from the array
     $scope.tasks.splice(index, 1);
 };
```

PS : *if you pass the `$index` through `ng-click` as `data-ng-click="removeRow($index)"` this will work only if there is no order by options in `ng-repeat` if you have sorting options then your deletion gets wrong. because when sorting is there `$index` is same as the (0,1,2,3) but array order may have changed (ex: 0-index element can lay in 1-index of sorted array so if you pass the $index then it will delete the 1st index of actual array) so $index not represent the actual array element.*

> sorting options => [`orderBy`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)

[UPDATED DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/Xr8tSfedNgOP93XF61WK?p=preview)

Comment: could you suggest any tutorial on this.. I have one more problem please see there is bounty on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31207250/how-to-allow-users-to-login-protected-flask-rest-api-in-angularjs

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

**View**

```
<a class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-ng-click="removeRow($index)">Delete</a>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.removeRow = function(index) {
   $scope.tasks.splice(index, 1);
};
```

Comment: If you find this question is sencefull then please upvote it

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhicould you suggest any tutorial on this.. I have one more problem please see there is bounty on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31207250/how-to-allow-users-to-login-protected-flask-rest-api-in-angularjs