# How to automatically login users to Pinterest (through URL) when redirecting from another website?

Tags: html, authentication, url, pinterest

In short I want to achieve the following, but cannot find how:

1. People navigate to my (internal) site, no login required
2. Someone clicks a button stating "Pinterest"
3. I redirect them to Pinterest and automatically log them into 'my' account

For an internal project I want to circumvent the hassle of requiring every user to login to Pinterest individually so they can access a specific private board. Instead, I want to allow everyone to use 'my' account (I trust all my users).

To make sure nobody has to remember the user credentials, I want to hardcode them into my site, submitting these credentials (presumably using the URL) whenever someone clicks the Pinterest link on my site.

I have reviewed the Pinterest API but cannot distinguish any such approach. Also reviewing the login form of Pinterest and tracing their submit routine didn't work out.

Other sites sometimes specify and/or allow a URL approach: [example](https://help.screensteps.com/m/administering/l/3528-how-do-i-embed-login-credentials-in-a-url).

A more generic approach was discussed (see below), but does not apply to this specific case. [How to automatically login to the site using url parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21426819/how-to-automatically-login-to-the-site-using-url-parameters)

Comment: _“Instead, I want to allow everyone to use 'my' account”_ - I think on pretty much any platform, that would violate their ToS already ... _“I have reviewed the Pinterest API but cannot distinguish any such approach”_ - well of course not, because that’s not how such APIs work, resp. it is not their purpose. Either use your own login and cache the data from the API server-side (so that you can then present it to your site visitors yourself), or make them login to Pinterest to use their account and its credentials. Everything else does not really make much sense.

Comment: @CBroe Besides the ToS stuff, I think they will do everything to prevent people from doing things like that. OAuth2 doen‘t work for interactive login for some reasons. Posting cleartext uid/pwd to their login site might work but is an awfull hack and a maintenave nightmare. Consider telling evrery trusted person your login credentials ...